# ipconfig doesn't recognize chinese characters in the SSID

Tags: ip, dhcp, static-ip, ipconfig

I'm overly confused: I set up my laptop's IP address at a static value (the last useful address pf the DHCP), then I input `ipconfig /renew`, checked and the laptop address is still the old address.

How should I trigger the router to assign the correct static IP to my laptop?

edit: I reworded the title to fit the actual problem. I see no solution for this, but using only Latin characters in the SSID is not a big problem

Comment: How did you setup the static address?  In the router or on your computer?

Comment: You're question doesn't make sense as-is. A "Static" IP address is a non-changing IP that you manually enter into the device (PC), and DHCP isn't used.  DHCP supplies "Dynamic" IP addresses on request. So which are you using? did you type the address into the PC manually, or is the PC set to "obtain automatically"?  Or are you talking about a DHCP Reservation?

Comment: Also, assuming this is Windows, `ipconfig \renew` isn't valid. Switch options are designated with a forward slash, not a backslash. So it should be `ipconfig /renew`.

Comment: @techie007 I'm talking about DHCP reservation, which is commonly described as "static IP" (amongst other, by the router manual, for example)

Comment: @techie007 I mistyped `/` in the question

Comment: @heavyd I did in the network properties interface of Windows, I'm looking for a way to do it from the router right now.

Answer (score 1):

So I assume by “static IP” you mean you set the DCHP service to always assign the same address.

As your question already correctly assumes, you need to release your current DHCP lease. Doing that is pretty easy with Windows:

```
ipconfig /release
```

After that, make your computer get a new lease:

```
ipconfig /renew
```

Theoretically, the DHCP service could also deny renewing the old lease. In that case, `ipconfig /renew` would be sufficient. However, that doesn’t seem to be the case here.

Comment: It's not working..  the lease date of the local address is still dating back to yesterday and it will expire later today.

Comment: @maja Why do you think that's a problem? The IP address was first assigned yesterday, and the lease has to expire some time, right?

Comment: @DavidSchwarts what I meant was that the lease using the old local address was still valid, so renew didn't effectively assign a new address (with a new lease)

Answer (score 0):

while trying a few additional commands like `ipconfig /release all` I realized that I had set up the wired connection while I needed the wireless connection.

I had already tried to edit the wireless connection but since I had no results I went beck to the generic "local area". it turned out ipconfig wasn't recognizing my actual wireless connection, I assume because the SSID was in Chinese characters

I changed the SSID to Latin characters and when I connected again the network was using the right local address.